# Sort array multidimensional by first subarray

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array and I want to sort it:

```
$ArrayStock = array(array("SIZE","L","XL","M"),("STOCK","12","3","2"));
```

How can I sort the array by "SIZE"?

Alternatively, I could use this array as a starting point:

```
$ArrayStock = array(array("L","XL","M"),("12","3","2"));
```

Comment: you can't, because for some stupid reason "size" is part of your array and not a key

Comment: ok, how to sort if i delete "size" and "stock" ? so like this $ArrayStock = array(array("L","XL","M"),("12","3","2"));

Comment: make it associative

Comment: make a `usort()` function

Comment: It probably would be easier to change your array to be $arrayStock = [
    'size' => [
        "L" => [
            'stock' => 12
        ],
        "XL" => [
            'stock' => 3
        ],
        "M" => [
            'stock' => 3
        ]
    ]
];

Comment: i tried usort but not working.

Comment: What part was "not working" in `usort()`? What code did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be a few ways to skin this cat.  All of my methods will produce the expected output...

First, let's do it without restructuring your array ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/903dfff7925a4ece96e4e381aac4ea2432ecfd42)):

```
$order=["XS","S","M","L","XL","2XL","3XL"];  // declare appropriate size order
$ArrayStock=[["L","XL","M"],["12","3","2"]];

// Order the first subarray:
uasort($ArrayStock[0],function($a,$b)use($order){
    return (array_search($a,$order)>array_search($b,$order)?1:-1);  // any unidentifed sizes will go to the front
});

// Sync the second subarray with first subarray:
$ArrayStock[1]=array_replace($ArrayStock[0],$ArrayStock[1]);

// Optionally re-index the keys:
$ArrayStock[0]=array_values($ArrayStock[0]);
$ArrayStock[1]=array_values($ArrayStock[1]);
```

---

---

Next I'll show a few ways that you can manipulate a restructured array.  There is absolutely nothing wrong with the way that trincot has written his. These are just alternatives that I've come up with...

I agree with trincot about using sizes as keys (because they will be unique) and stock counts as values.  So the first process is to generate that new array structure:

```
$ArrayStock=[["L","XL","M"],["12","3","2"]];
```

**#1** One-liner `array_combine()` approach:

```
$new_structure=array_combine($ArrayStock[0],$ArrayStock[1]);
//  $new_structure = ['L'=>'12','XL'=>'3','M'=>'2']
```

**#2** `foreach()` approach:

```
foreach($ArrayStock[0] as $i=>$size){
    $new_structure[$size]=$ArrayStock[1][$i];
}
//  $new_structure = ['L'=>'12','XL'=>'3','M'=>'2']
```

---

Now to sort the new array, you can use `uksort()` or a range of other array functions / loops with your predetermined order array:

```
$order=["XS","S","M","L","XL","2XL","3XL"];  // declare whatever appropriate sizes in order
```

**#1** `uksort()` with `array_search()` approach:

```
uksort($new_structure,function($a,$b)use($order){
    return (array_search($a,$order)>array_search($b,$order)?1:-1);
    // any unidentified sizes will go to the front of the array
});
// keep in mind, this doesn't declare $result, it sorts $new_structure
```

**#2** `array_replace()` with `array_flip()`-`array_intersect()`-`array_keys()` approach:

```
$result=array_replace(                         // replace values on matching keys
            array_flip(                        // swap keys with values
                array_intersect(
                    $order,                    // keep values from here
                    array_keys($new_structure) // that exist here
                )
            ),
        $new_structure);                       // use these elements for replace
// $result=['M'=>'2','L'=>'12','XL'=>'3'];
```

**#3** `foreach()` with `array_intersect()`-`array_keys()` approach:

```
// generate & iterate ordered array
foreach(array_intersect($order,array_keys($new_structure)) as $v){
    $result[$v]=$new_structure[$v];      // build properly sorted array
}
// $result=['M'=>'2','L'=>'12','XL'=>'3'];
```

---

Finally as trincot has shown, you *can* revert the sorted data back to the initial format with one more one-liner:

```
$ArrayStock=[array_keys($result),array_values($result)];
```

Comment: @HengkyST  Sorry for the long-winded answer.  You can most-simply just use the two step method that I start with, or you can restructure your array and use any of the many techniques to sort the data.  I mostly wanted to use your question to educate readers.  Let me know if anything doesn't work for you or if you don't understand something I've written.

Comment: I Very Thanks full for complate tutorial $ArrayStock @mickmackusa, i try and it's work for me.

Comment: @HengkyST The pleasure is mine. I always learn more by experimenting/teaching.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
// Combine into one associative array
$combined = array_combine($ArrayStock[0], $ArrayStock[1]);

// Rebuild it in the correct order:
foreach(["SIZE", "S","M","L","XL","XXL"] as $size) {
    if (isset($combined[$size])) $result[$size] = $combined[$size];
}

// Split associative array back to its original structure:
$ArrayStock = [array_keys($result), array_values($result)];
```

Note that this structure is not so practical in its use. I would in fact stick with the associative array.